# First PCB (raspberry pi hat)... can't find short circuit

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, short-circuit

INTRO:
Hi there, everyone. I'm working on a RaspberryPi hat PCB that drives 10 solenoids and takes in 5 inputs. I designed the PCB on EasyEDA and had the boards printed at JLCPCB and used their SMT service to pick and place the components.

ISSUE:
When I plug the power supply in, the voltage drops from 24V to negligible millivolts. When the power supply is unplugged I can read 24V fine. Two components get warm after about 2 or 3 minutes at which point I unplug the power supply to hopefully not damage anything (Q1 and U2 as seen below).

I would be grateful if someone could take a look at the schematic and the pcb layout and possibly give me direction on where to go from here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Things I have Tried:

- Continuity test across U1 input terminals beeps for a short bit and then stops... I have figured this is from a capacitor filling up.
- I have tried putting an LED across the 5V and GND pins where the raspberry pi usually sits to see if I needed to draw some load but this had no effect.

I have not tried plugging a raspberry pi in as I don't want to damage the pins.

Possibly Helpful Notes:
Power Supply - 24VDC 2.1A |
Solenoids - 24V .2A |
Sensors - 24V |
Raspberry Pi 4 - 5V 2A

I am a complete novice at circuit board design and electricity in general, if I left any information out of this post that is needed let me know and I will hopefully clarify as quickly as I can.

Thank you for any help you can provide,

Daniel Cloran

UPDATE: I have fixed the short based on brhans help... the D1 diode was flipped! I am working on adding an output capacitor based on the datasheet.

I am now using a different board with a replaced Q1, and I am getting about 1.7 V out where 5V is supposed to be. I have been reading the Fine Manual and know you can calculate output voltage with Vout = 1.239 * (R1+R2) / R2... (R3 and R4 in my case) which should give 5V's out - 4.956V = 1.239 * (30+10) / 10. I've measured the ohms of the resisters, reading about 18k and 8k on this board, 24k and 10k on a different board... these should still give values above 1.7V. Would the output capacitor increase this voltage in some way or just smooth the voltage? Any ideas?

Adding the output capacitor fixed the problem! Thank you all for the help... the board works as intended for now, but I will work on fixing the tracing issues in V2.

Comment: Your board doesn't match your schematic...

Comment: i do not see any solenoid drivers in the schematic ... please post the complete circuit schematic

Comment: I had only included the power supply module from the schematic in the post... apologies, the post now has the raspberrypi module and the solenoid drivers.

Comment: Your main problem is that you have D1 wired up backwards. Once you fix that though your routing around U2 and Q1 is horrible - you need short fat traces between those 2 and their caps C1 & C5. And that tiny spindly little ground trace from U2 pin-2, the trace from Q1 up & down thru single vias to L1 ...

Comment: Vias in pads are rarely a good idea unless you're so tight on space that it's unavoidable - I'm a little surprised that your fab people didn't say anything. Hasn't all the solder paste just flowed into the holes and not left much on the pads? The vias and bottom-layer trace from Q1-gate over to U2 pin-7 is also unnecessary - you have a straight shot to connect them on the top layer.

Comment: I will go solder D1 the opposite way... and update the post. I sort of knew that the routing around this whole board wasn't ideal... would those short and fat traces be solely to prevent voltage drop and heat or are there other reasons too?

Comment: There is no longer a short! Thank you! The voltage where the schematic says 5V is 24V however... any ideas?

Comment: Q1 has probably died and is now emulating a wire link (due to it trying valiantly but ultimately failing to pull the backward D1 up to 24V).

Comment: Also - I'm not seeing an output cap anywhere in your design. Refer to the [Fine Manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3489.pdf), page 15, fig 25 for a 'Typical Application Schematic' and note Cout on the right side, and page 16, section 8.2.2.2 'Output Capacitor Selection'.

Comment: Alright so I am now using a different board with a replaced Q1, and I am getting about 1.7 V out where 5V is supposed to be. I have been reading the Fine Manual and know you can calculate output voltage with Vout = 1.239 * (R1+R2) / R2... (R3 and R4 in my case) which should give 5V's out - 4.956V = 1.239 * (30+10) / 10. I've measured the ohms of the resisters, reading about 18k and 8k on this board, 24k and 10k on a different board... these should still give values above 1.7V. Would the output capacitor increase this voltage in some way or just smooth the voltage? Any ideas?

Comment: Also, thanks a million for your help on this, you have been amazing and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you using **two** DMMT5401 dual transistor arrays in your ideal diode circuit?

Comment: On the KiCad raspberry pi template, they put that as a protecter circuit that your power supply should feed into... I didn't entirely know if this was redundant so I added it in figuring it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You're mixing 24Vdc with gpio on the one connector. That sounds like a recipe for disaster. The raspi gpio aren’t designed to go out to the real world and require filtering and protection. As others have mentioned, your power tracks look way too thin and the psu layout is unlikely to work properly.