# 24Vdc to 5Vdc 3A Buck Regulator over-heating

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, buck

The last time I asked a question on this forum you were all incredibly helpful thank you for that: [First PCB (raspberry pi hat)... can't find short circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541248/first-pcb-raspberry-pi-hat-cant-find-short-circuit), I have an extension on this previous question.

**Problem:** The LM3489 chip (supposedly rated for max current of 4A) used previously became very hot to the touch (drawing around 500mA... chip does not get hot at all under no load) and while all of the components worked for > 30 min I am worried about the continuous use of this overheating chip. I understand that the tracing on the previous board was horrible and I did not follow the recommended layout at the bottom of the data sheet, but the only example circuits that I found demonstrating the LM3489 show between 100-500mA outputs, nowhere near the 3A that I need. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3489.pdf?ts=1612195295134&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Working (but hot) Schematic for LM3489:
[image]
Current Bad Layout:
[image]

**Question:** Why was the LM3489 getting so hot (tracing just that bad / chip can't actually run pulling 3A)? Will fixing the layout to match the recommended on the data sheet fix the heat?

I would really like to avoid another costly round of boards not working, so any help at all that you can provide would be immensely appreciated.

**What I have now tried:** Switched out C2 with a lower capacitor 100nF to 1nF with no success (board did not produce 5V out and became really hot under no load).

If any parts of this post are confusing or if I should provide any other helpful information, please let me know and I will update the information as soon as I can.

Comment: It would appear that the LM3489 controller can regulate 4A with an external FET while without is limited by the 6 ~8 Ohm internal FETs to about 400mA with some duty cycle .

Comment: In the schematic linked in the previous post I attempted to use a "P-Channel -60V 3A 3V @ 250uA 105mΩ @ 3A,10V 1.6W SOT-23-6 MOSFET RoHS" as the external PFET which would allow for 3A or did I implement that incorrectly?

Comment: Would you mind reposting the schematic of your actual board here? I know it’s linked from your other SE post but I had to scratch my head for a minute to find which of these inline schematics was the right one for your LM3489 solution.

Comment: Added "Working (but hot) Schematic for LM3489" under Problem:

Comment: C2 100nF conducts all the high frequency noise to the FB pin which makes the driver switch more often trying to reduce ripple that it by this cap is creating from hysteresis as there is not fixed clock inside. The faster it switches, the more energy is dissipated.   Although claimed this "compensation cap" is not necessary, one example shows 100pF in the feedback divider.

Comment: I will swap out C2 with a 100pF capacitor and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I removed the capacitor and the board ran fine not under load, but when I added load the LM3489 chip made a hissing noise and shut off... I soldered back on the 100nF and the board worked as expected again, just hot. The closest I have to a 100pF is a 1000pF so I will try using that now.

Comment: With 1nF the LM3489 chip got very hot not under load and did not give the intended voltage output.

Comment: Your layout could be improved. Do yo have a solid ground plane? Your C5-Q1-D1-L1-C3 loop should be as small as possible.

Comment: I do not have a solid ground plane on this design, I will be adding that to the updated layout. The large red blob was an attempt at a ground section but not very successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Problem: The LM3489 chip (supposedly rated for max current of 4A)...

The [LM3489](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3489.pdf?ts=1612297223398&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM3489) is a PFET Buck *Controller*. Maximum current is determined by which external FET, inductor and flyback diode are used.

> the only example circuits that I found demonstrating the LM3489 show
> between 100-500mA outputs, nowhere near the 3A that I need.

You can use the LM3489 in a higher current design, but you will have to upgrade the external components to handle it.

The [FDC5614P](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDC5614P-D.PDF) supposedly has a maximum current rating of 3 A when when mounted on a 1in<sup>2</sup> pad of 2oz copper on FR-4 board. In practice you would not want to do that because the FET would run extremely hot and have a high chance of burning out, as well as heating up other components around it. In your circuit the FET should only be conducting for a part of each cycle so you might get way with it, but for safety I would choose a device with much lower R<sub>DSON</sub>.

If a 22 μH inductor is appropriate for 0.5 A then for 3 A you may need a smaller value to avoid saturation (4.7 μH is a typical value used in regulators with similar sized inductors).

When converting from 24 V to 5 V the flyback diode will have to pass ~80% of the average output current, ie. 2.4 A at 3 A. The [MBRS140](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBRS140T3-D.PDF) is only rated for 1 A.

To determine the best components for your application I suggest you either simulate the circuit, or copy an existing design with similar specs. Ti's reference design [PMP7771](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP7771) uses a FET with 0.021 Ω R<sub>DSON</sub>, a 5.6 μH inductor, and a 3 A Schottky diode.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate thought is that the current limiter may be kicking in. Section `8.2.2.4` of the datasheet says that you can disable the current limiter by tying `ADJ` to `GND` and `ISENSE` to `VIN`. As a quick experiment, can you try doing this and see if your max current increases? (This will involve desoldering three passives and adding a couple of external wires, or making a breadboard version of your circuit.)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reach the boards until tomorrow, but I think the ADJ and ISENSE are connect as per data sheet recommendation (see updated post with previous schematic). I will see about running this test and update as soon as I can get to them.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the test you want me to run, with the current configuration of ADJ to VIN and ISENSE to the FET gate I am not sure what to do?

Comment: I’m simply suggesting to try temporarily disabling the current limiter according to the datasheet. Referring to your schematic, you will have to desolder `R1`, `R2`, and `C4`, then solder a wire from the `ADJ` pin to `GND` and solder another wire from the `ISENSE` pin to `VIN`.